# Short Story with strange Electronic components and Modules from catalog

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I think I read this in an anthology. Some guys start to order parts from mail catalog, super-transistors and other components that are really sent by aliens. I cannot really remember how it ended. Does anyone know the title?

Answer (score 7):

Isn't that the plot of [This Island Earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Island_Earth_%28novel%29)? That was serialised at first before it became a novel.

As user14111 comments, the story you're looking for was "[The Alien Machine](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?77624)" by [Raymond F. Jones](http://sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/jones_raymond_f).

The protagonist is an engineer who orders parts from a catalog and receives unexpected components and instructions to build a mysterious device called an "interocitor".

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. This is the one I was looking for.

Comment: @MikePoplas You can [accept](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) the answer by clicking on the check mark.